# "customer" Object only has "null" values when we post a customer

Tags: json, jackson, wildfly-10, json-view

have an application here which is using @JsonViews to manipulation the json output of entities from webservices.

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

@Id
@JsonView(ListView.class)
private String customerID;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 3)
@JsonView(DetailView.class)
private String companyName;
```

Webservice-Method:

```
    @POST
// also tested but not working with @JsonView(DetailView.class)
public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return customerService.updateCustomer(customer);
}
```

All worked fine in Wildfly 8 and 9, but on Wildfly 10 the "customer" Object only have "null" values when we post a customer. When i remove "@JsonViews" from the Customer-Object the properties without any jsonview will be used correctly.

Any ideas why Wildfly 10 has another behaving as the previous versions and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

PS: GET Requestes with JSONViews work as expected

```
@GET
@JsonView(DetailView.class)
public Customer getCustomerById....
```

Answer (score 0):

@JSONView for deserialization is allowed since Jackson 2.5.
If the datamodel is using JSONView it seems that you have to declare the json view you want to use while post/put, BUT at parameter level:

```
@POST
public Customer updateCustomer( @JsonView(DetailView.class) Customer customer) { ...
```

Wildfly 9 is using Jackson 2.4.X = JSONView is not supported for deserialization, so here it is working as i expected.